# Referencing document from frame using Jquery

Tags: html

If a frame is placed inside a document, I currently can reference any child in the document from inside the frame using regular JavaScript:

```
frames.window.document.getElementById("whatever")
```

How can I do the same using Jquery?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could get the document in jquery like this:

```
$(frames.window.document).find('#myid');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It didn't work, but this works: $(frames.parent.document).find("#myid");